# Modules reload/reset after setup

Tags: node.js, jestjs, puppeteer

I'm trying to avoid using `global` object because I want to use `strict mode` so I'm trying to use global module strategy:

**Browser.js**

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    instance: null
};
```

I'm using Puppeteer, so I'm setting up an appropriate environment ([example](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/puppeteer.html))

**setup.js** (Full setup code can be found on example link):

```js
const Browser = require("../Browser");

module.exports = async function () {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    // store the browser instance so we can teardown it later
    Browser.instance = browser;
};
```

But, when I'm enter to the tests, Browser module instance is set to `null` again as if the module reload again ie:.

**index.test.js**

```js
const Browser = require('../Browser');

let page;

beforeAll(async function() {
    page = await Browser.instance.newPage(); // Browser.instance = null
});
```

Also, in other setup file, that run before the tests actually starts, the browser have the instance as expected:

**PuppeteerEnvironment.js**

```js
const Browser = require("../Browser"); 

async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    // get the wsEndpoint
    const wsEndpoint = fs.readFileSync(path.join(DIR, 'wsEndpoint'), 'utf8');
    if (!wsEndpoint) {
        throw new Error('wsEndpoint not found');
    }

    console.log(Browser.instance); // print the Browser object as expected
    // connect to puppeteer
    await puppeteer.connect({
        browserWSEndpoint: wsEndpoint,
    });
}
```

My goal is to have only one browser instance that will be easy to access.

Comment: your `setup.js` exported method is not writing anything into some kind of global object, not `return`ing anything. And in example link you've provided some global variable is set. try returning something or debigging/console.log the setup.js to see if it is executed during start up of tests/each test.

Comment: Thanks, the global object is `Browser` module. the `setup.js` execute once when `jest` start (and not before each test). Also, the `Browser` object update is reflected in `PuppeteerEnvironment.js`.

Comment: `Broswer` in thing that get's exported from `./Browser` module, not a global object. AFAIK it's true that Node actually loads/runs it once, and then when you `require` it will give you back same singleton object, like from cache. so if you modify it it will be reflected everywhere.

Comment: I know the same, and it also works (in `PuppeteerEnvironment.js`) but I think the `Jest` tests run on isolated environment or something like this.

Comment: so use https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfiles-array

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to do this, because `await puppeteer.launch();` (in `setup.js` is expensive operation, and `setupFiles` execute before each *test* (not once before `jest` run its tests)